# Unit testing a Grails Service class containing the withRest closure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, closures

Building a Grails 2.2.4 application that uses a service class to make REST calls to another server.  Code in the service class looks something like this:

```
def get( .. ){
    withRest( .. ){
        def response = get(..)
        Here begins the code I really need to test.
    }
}
```

How can I mock the "get" method within the "withRest" closure so I can perform unit tests against this class?  I want to return my own "mocked" JSON response.

I don't think I want to mock the "withRest" closure itself as the logic I need to test is found within the closure (and I don't know how to mock the closure anyway)

**Update**

Using REST Client plugin
`compile ":rest:0.1"`

Here's what a valid segment of code would look like:

```
def get() { 
   withRest(uri: "yahoo.com") { 
      def response = get() 
      println "response=$response" 
   } 
}
```

I want to mock the "get" method and return my own response.

Comment: Can you clarify on which REST client you use and/or how is `withRest` tailored?

Comment: compile ":rest:0.1"
Here's what a valid segment of code would look like:
    def get() {
      withRest(uri: "http://www.yahoo.com") {
        def response = get()
        println "response=$response"
      }
    }
I want to mock the "get" method and return my own response.

Comment: I pulled the withRest closure and "get" call into a seperate class.  That way I can test my business logic and not test the REST Plugin/HTTPBuilder.  But now I need to mock the response (an instance of HttpResponseDecorator).  Any ideas?